# FastAI resizing works counterintuitive

Tags: python, image, fast-ai

I'm trying to use fastai for categorization purpose. I've splitted my images in to 3 directories: train, test and val, images are in different shapes.

This code produces "desirable" output with image scaled correctly:

```
from fastai.vision.all import *

train_dataloader = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(
    path="data",
    train="train",
    test = "test",
    valid="val",
    bs=1,
    seed=42,
    batch_tfms=[*aug_transforms(size=(244,244)),
                Normalize.from_stats(*imagenet_stats)],
)

train_dataloader.show_batch()
```

[image: "Correct" output]

But when I try to increase bs parameter and then call train_dataloader.show_batch() I've got error suggesting that images haven't been reshaped.

```
from fastai.vision.all import *

train_dataloader = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(
    path="data",
    train="train",
    test = "test",
    valid="val",
    bs=2,
    seed=42,
    batch_tfms=[*aug_transforms(size=(244,244)),
                Normalize.from_stats(*imagenet_stats)],
)

train_dataloader.show_batch()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [13], line 1
----> 1 train_dataloader.show_batch()

File c:\USERS\DAWID\ANACONDA3\ENVS\415\lib\site-packages\fastai\data\core.py:149, in TfmdDL.show_batch(self, b, max_n, ctxs, show, unique, **kwargs)
    147     old_get_idxs = self.get_idxs
    148     self.get_idxs = lambda: Inf.zeros
--> 149 if b is None: b = self.one_batch()
    150 if not show: return self._pre_show_batch(b, max_n=max_n)
    151 show_batch(*self._pre_show_batch(b, max_n=max_n), ctxs=ctxs, max_n=max_n, **kwargs)

File c:\USERS\DAWID\ANACONDA3\ENVS\415\lib\site-packages\fastai\data\load.py:172, in DataLoader.one_batch(self)
    170 def one_batch(self):
    171     if self.n is not None and len(self)==0: raise ValueError(f'This DataLoader does not contain any batches')
--> 172     with self.fake_l.no_multiproc(): res = first(self)
    173     if hasattr(self, 'it'): delattr(self, 'it')
    174     return res

File c:\USERS\DAWID\ANACONDA3\ENVS\415\lib\site-packages\fastcore\basics.py:660, in first(x, f, negate, **kwargs)
    658 x = iter(x)
    659 if f: x = filter_ex(x, f=f, negate=negate, gen=True, **kwargs)
--> 660 return next(x, None)

File c:\USERS\DAWID\ANACONDA3\ENVS\415\lib\site-packages\fastai\data\load.py:127, in DataLoader.__iter__(self)
    125 self.before_iter()
    126 self.__idxs=self.get_idxs() # called in context of main process (not workers/subprocesses)
--> 127 for b in _loaders[self.fake_l.num_workers==0](self.fake_l):
    128     # pin_memory causes tuples to be converted to lists, so convert them back to tuples
    129     if self.pin_memory and type(b) == list: b = tuple(b)
    130     if self.device is not None: b = to_device(b, self.device)

File c:\USERS\DAWID\ANACONDA3\ENVS\415\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:628, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    625 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    626     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    627     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 628 data = self._next_data()
    629 self._num_yielded += 1
    630 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    631         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    632         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File c:\USERS\DAWID\ANACONDA3\ENVS\415\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:671, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    669 def _next_data(self):
    670     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
...
Mismatch found on axis 0 of the batch and is of type `TensorImage`:
    Item at index 0 has shape: torch.Size([3, 644, 800])
    Item at index 1 has shape: torch.Size([3, 420, 630])

Please include a transform in `after_item` that ensures all data of type TensorImage is the same size
```

I've tried other pythons version, reinsatlled FastAI via pip and anaconda, this one is from
python 3.10.8 and fastai 2.7.10
I've also tried Resize insted of aug_transforms(size=(244,244)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from future me:
You have to add paramiter item_tfms with argument Resize(244).

```
from fastai.vision.all import *

train_dataloader = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(
    path="data",
    train="train",
    test = "test",
    valid="val",
    bs=2,
    seed=42,
    item_tfms = Resize(244),
    batch_tfms=[*aug_transforms(size=(244,244)),
                Normalize.from_stats(*imagenet_stats)],
)

train_dataloader.show_batch()
```